# Performance limits of file I/O vs Unix pipes on multicore systems

Tags: ubuntu, pipe, limit

I am running some benchmarks where I have a program that performs some file IO. It creates a fresh directory, writes and reads some files to that directory, and then deletes it. When I run this program on multiple cores, running more instances of this procedure at once, I get expected results (some speedup, that starts to flatten out as I near the limit of my machine. Going from 1 to 12 cores made the program 8.5x faster).

I have a second variant of this same program that doesn't use file IO. It instead opens pipes and passes the data around through these pipes, chaining commands together. At most, it will open 3 pipes at once.
Even sequentially, this program is naturally much faster (about 10x). However, when I start to add more cores, it starts to flatten out very fast; at three cores it seems to flatten out completely, with a 2x speedup. From 3 to 12 cores there is no deterioration, either. The execution speed remains pretty much the same. No improvement or degradation.

There is some resource that is running out that I don't understand. I am guessing that there is some cap associated with Unix pipes that I don't know of. I've tried to find details online but have not found anything that sounds suspicious. I am at most sending 100 characters through a pipe at once. **Are there any limitations to how many Unix pipes I can have open at once? I find it weird how I can add more workers that open more pipes, and performance does not increase nor decrease.**

Comment: I think your description of the usage of files and the usage of pipes in the parallelized case is really not quite clear enough to give a reasonable accurate answer; would you mind describing how much data you exchange, across how many files, and whether "downstream" processing already starts while upstream is still writing data to the files or pipes, or whether it only starts once the producing program is done. Very helpful to know would be in which size of "chunk" the writing program produces data, too.

Comment: Yes, your results indicate the bottleneck is not related to the number of parallel processes/threads you are using.  Pipes can buffer far more than 100 bytes before blocking the sender.  I suggest trying your tests with larger amounts written to and read from the pipes, and see how the results change.

Comment: In case it matters, what is the underlying device for the directory? Standard spinning rust or ssd, tmpfs, NFS, or even a cluster file system providing parallel access to NVMe devices? And with newer kernels, you can set the pipe buffer size. Don't know if that matters here but it might be worth playing with. How much data are you passing around in a single chunk?